# Best way to store and access data with WordPress?

Tags: javascript, json, database, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using a payment system which does not allow me to make quantity limitation.

So if I want to limit the purchases of a product A to a number X, I can't do it natively.

The website I am using is a WordPress with LeadPages onto it.

I want to be able to store my value X globally and each time a purchase is registered I will decrement X until X = 0 and disable the purchase button.

I thought about creating a DB in WordPress but I am not sure it is the best solution. Because the credentials to access it would be visible on the client side javascript code.

I also saw this solution with JSON Data : [REST API - youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAl9m-yCwGA)

But again, I am not really sure if it is valid solution.

Thank you for your help on this :-)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question.  Here is a good place to start - [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I understand but it is a bit of vicious circle here... If I want to show some code or have specific request I need to know where to start or at least dig in the right direction. I already made some research and I am not really at ease with WP plus it is not my WP so I am even more careful with what I try.

Comment: Well, I understand your dilemma. However, this site (stackoverflow) is not the place to ask open ended questions. I don't know where you would go, but it's likely that nobody here answers your question (if it's not closed) since it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about creating a DB in WordPress

Please don't. WordPress already has pretty much everything you would need to manage data, and more.

> I want to be able to store my value X globally

Look at [WordPress Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

> I want to limit the purchases of a product A to a number X

Assuming the `product` is [a CPT](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/), have a read on custom fields and [post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/)

Also, check out the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/) and pretty much the full developer's handbook of WP because what you are asking is definitely achievable with WordPress. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you ! I will look into in and I will post what I have made out of this :-)